# OverloadedLabels in IHP

Tags: haskell, ihp

## Context

The IHP Guide has a section that describes their use of hash symbols:

https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/helpful-tips.html

It mentions the following:

> Writing `#companyId` is equivalent to writing `fromLabel @"companyId"`.

## Experiment

In the example blog application, if I add the following to a view:

```
{get #title post}
```

The title of the post shows up as expected.

Now, if I add the following to the view instead:

```
{get (fromLabel @"title") post}
```

the page doesn't render properly and it gives me the following message:

```
Web/View/Posts/Show.hs:11:33
    • 12:40:
   |
12 |         {get (fromLabel @"title") post}
   |                                        ^
"0\nSrcLoc \"\" 1 30\nParse error in expression: fromLabel@\"title\"\n"
```

## Question

Based on the what is mentioned in the documentation cited above, it seemed that I could write:

```
get (fromLabel @"title") post
```

instead of:

```
get #title post
```

But that clearly does not work. :-)

So, what am I missing here? Is there a way to write:

```
get #title post
```

in terms of `fromLabel`?

## Update 1

As suggested by Fyodor in a comment below, I tried the following:

```
{show @Int 42}
```

This was the result:

```
Web/View/Posts/Show.hs:11:33
    • 12:23:
   |
12 |         {show @Int 42}
   |                       ^
"0\nSrcLoc \"\" 1 13\nParse error in expression: show@Int\n"
```

Comment: I think it's just a bug in the template compiler. Can you try something like `{show @Int 42}`?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, yup, that also causes a similar message. (I updated the question with the results.)

Comment: Have you turned on the `TypeApplications` extension (e.g. by writing `{-# Language TypeApplications #-}` at the top of your file)? If not, try it.

Comment: @DanielWagner, when I add that, the results are the same.

Comment: The template parser seems to remove whitespace around operators, converting `foo @bar` to `foo@bar`, not realizing that this changes the meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE: This is fixed with IHP v0.20 and now works as expected**

This is a known bug :-)

See https://github.com/digitallyinduced/ihp/issues/1049 and https://github.com/digitallyinduced/ihp/issues/857

Try writing it like this:

```
[hsx|{title}|]
    where
        title = get (fromLabel @"title") post
```

Inside HSX expressions the haskell code inside `{}` is parsed using a custom haskell parser (not the one used by the haskell compiler). The custom parser is a bit outdated and doesn't support the `@SomeType` syntax yet.

The `#hash` syntax is also not supported directly by the parser. The parser thinks that the `#` symbol is an infix operator (like `+` or `-`). HSX later transforms the infix expressions with `#` into the correct `fromLabel` call.

With recent versions of the haskell compiler we can actually get rid of the third-party parser entirely and use the haskell compiler parser directly. We plan to do that in the future to fix this issue.